# How to determine if selectable list chosen

Tags: jquery

I need to create a function to do something if a specific selectable list is chosen and show an alert.

```
<select name="location" data-c="location" class="filter valid cc_cursor" aria-invalid="false">
    <option value="" selected="selected">-</option>
    <option value="2">Newyork Clinic</option>
    <option value="1">Center Hospital</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You have asked this same question about 3 times with various different accounts. Firstly, please read the reason for the closures each time. In addition, repeatedly asking the same question with multiple accounts is likely to get you banned.

Comment: Onkar Singh solved my problem.if you give more effort for solve problems and help people instead of close question, may it will be better for humanity

Comment: Look at the reason the question was closed. There is a link to a pre-existing question which already details the code you need to use.

Comment: understand the same thing, similar issues are addressed into another post, but sometimes another side non-technical person and can't able to understand, and they want to answer over their own question, so I have comments and try to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `change` event to detect the value of select tag

```js
jQuery(function($){
  $(document).on('change', 'select[name="location"]', function(){
    if( $(this).val() != '' ){
      alert('option selected...');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="location" data-c="location" class="filter valid cc_cursor" aria-invalid="false">
<option value="" selected="selected">-</option>
<option value="2">
Newyork Clinic</option>
<option value="1">Center Hospital</option>
</select>
```

Comment: your jquery code freeze my laptop when it opened.does it create a endless loop? I use google chrome,linux

Comment: Nopes, are you able to share the URL with code added to the website, then I am able to check and debug it

Comment: thanks for your helping.I changed alert code to real code and there is no problem now